# Java how to deploy socket server web application?

Tags: java, sockets

I wrote an application with front end in js and back end in java. It is supposed to be a socket application. In js I use standard socket javascript client. In java I use classes from packages `javax.websocket`, so the essential class has the annotation `@ServerEndpoint("/server")`. I deployed my app on openshift and only client is working. When I try to connect to the server(url looks like `ws://address.of.my.page.on.cloud/server`) I get the console alert in firefox that the connection with socket server could not be done. I guess maybe openshift isn't suppose to handle sockets but I could not find any servers that provide such possibility for free. Are there any out there? Or maybe I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Does it work locally?

Comment: Doing a simple google for "openshift websockets" provided this as the first hit: https://blog.openshift.com/paas-websockets/ . Since its clearly supported, the answer is "you're doing something wrong". The document clearly indicates you need to use a specific port.

Comment: @ChrisThompson yes, it is working locally, I forgot to mention it, sorry. @Gimby yes! The answer is the port, all I needed to do is add the `:8000` to the url, problem solved ;) It is interesting that I didn't find that oin research...